# Creating additional characters for an existing font?

Tags: font-design, character

A font I am using is missing a couple special characters so I made my own. I'm trying to package them together as a typeface using [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io).  However without knowing the original font's metrics I can't get the scale right. I might be going about this totally wrong, any suggestions?

Edit: I also have concerns about usage rights considering this is a paid font. To be clear I do not plan to distribute the custom font I am creating, just use it on my site and for print work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a proprietary font then please check the EULA agreement that accompanies the font. Most proprietary fonts do not allow disassembly/modification of the font and this is usually mentioned in the EULA. So I'm afraid that this might not be possible.

If you use a Libre (open source) font then you would have no problems doing this. So, it really depends on what font you wish to modify and under what license it was released.